# Best practice for updating a view with data/content?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

In Android, when should (and shouldn't) a view (activity/fragment) be updated with content?

**`TextView`**'s shouldn't be set with text from the same thread **`OnCreate()`** is running on, correct, but instead set on the UI thread (which is done by posting statements to the UI threads **`MessageQueue`**)?

95% of my view's set data (in **`TextViews`**, **`TabHosts`**, **`Checkboxes`**, etc... ) directly in **`OnCreate()`** (or a function called from it) and works fine, but I realize now that just b/c I've been getting away with it doesn't mean it's right (yes i'm getting bit now).

However, running on the UI thread isn't enough, I'm finding I need to post from **`OnResume()`** for 100% guarantee that the **`RecordView`** will updated as expected.

1. The code below show's the two scenarios for calling **`UpdateView()`**. Is it enough to call **`UpdateView()`**  in **`OnResume()`** to ensure the **`RecordView`** will display with populated data as expected, or is there a better, more correct and/or preferred way of doing this?
2. Also, is **`_thisView`** redundant to **`_container`**?
3. Is the **`RecordView`** that is having it's **`OnCreate()`** being called the same **`RecordView`** that is displayed? Why do I need to inflate the **`RecordView`** in **`OnCreate()`**, and then return it out? Shouldn't this happen automatically by the runtime, before **`OnCreate()`** is called (it's almost like a Factory pattern or something)?

   ---

**Example Code**:

```
public class RecordView : Fragment
{
    private Bundle _bundle;
    private ViewGroup _container;
    private LayoutInflater _inflater;

    ViewGroup _thisView;
    TextView _tvTitle, _tvField1, _tvField2;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, bundle); 

        _inflater = inflater;
        _container = container;
        _bundle = bundle;   

        Render();

        return _thisView;
    }

    public override void Render()
    {
        _thisView = (ViewGroup) _inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Record, _container, false);

        _tvTitle = _thisView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv_title);          
        _tvField1 = _thisView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv_field_1);
        _tvField2 = _thisView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv_field_2);

        // *A* SOMETIMES WORKS - Title & fields sometimes blank
        UpdateView();

        // *B* SOMETIMES WORKS - Title & fields sometimes blank
        _thisView.Post(() => { UpdateView(); });
    }

    public override void OnResume()
    {       
        base.OnResume();

        // *C* SOMETIMES WORKS - Title & fields sometimes blank
        UpdateView();

        // *D* ALWAYS WORKS - Title & fields always display data as expected
        _thisView.Post(() => { UpdateView(); });
    }

    private void UpdateView()
    {           
        _tvTitle.Text = "Todo";             
        _tvField1.Text = "RTFM";
        _tvField2.Text = "ASAP";            
    }   
}
```

Comment: Updating view's from **`OnResume()`** is indeed more reliable, but significantly slower (though this slowness could've been what was interfering with setting content in **`OnCreateView()`**; the view is busy rendering). However, regardless of a views complexity, this delay introduced by **`OnResume()`** seems consistent (all involved views are fragments of the same **`ViewPager`**, so adding/removing them to/from it could very well account for this delay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should show initial data or some loading animation in `OnCreateView(..)`, load data in background and then post actual content on the main thread once it is available, i.E.:
`new Handler(Looper.GetMainLooper()).post(() => {
//update views here
});`

Also, setting a `View's` content in `OnCreateView(..)` ALWAYS works if you use one of the `View.set(..)` methods, in your case `TextView.setText(..)`.
That is because setters call `invalidate()` on the view which in turn redraws the view.

It is by design not possible that setting a `TextView's` text in `OnCreateView(..)` is not updated on screen.

**I FORGOT TO MENTION**
No, _thisView is not the same as _container.
_thisView is a direct child of _container.

Consider this:
Your main `layout.xml` is a `FrameLayout`.
you add a `Fragment` to it that has a layout called `frag.xml`, beeing a `TextView`.

now the _container is the `FrameLayout`, but _thisView is the `TextView`.

Comment: Is **`Looper.GetMainLooper`** the same looper thread I see near the top of every stack trace **`android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage`** < **`android.os.Looper.loop`** < **`android.app.ActivityThread.main`**? Thanks for clear answer.

Comment: yes it is. The Main looper handles View drawing, Input processing (Touch etc), amongst other things. As a matter of fact view contents can only be changed on the Main Thread, for that reason also known as UI thread. Hence calling setText(..) must be done on the Main Looper.

Comment: Threads can share memory (one of their main benefits), I wonder if it was a technical decision to not allow other threads to modify views, or consequence of the core design/implementation. Either way, I now know how it behaves which is all that really mattters. I would wager it is to simplify programming for it, since inter-thread communication still needs mutual exclusivity and all the fun overhead that goes along with it (race/locks). It would up the learning curve I'd imagine.

Comment: It was a technical decision alright, consider this: two threads try to update a view at the same time, which could in worst case leave the view drawn half by one half by the other. which means you need to synchronize access to the drawing layer anyway. synchronizing induces overhead for acquiring and releasing locks, also leads to a lot of boilerplate code, so why not enforce a 1-thread-policy and be done with it?

Comment: Interesting to know, thanks. I just posted another related question here if you are interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256342/can-updating-a-textview-off-the-ui-thread-cause-an-exception-in-it