# Can updating a TextView off the UI Thread cause an exception in it?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

If a **`View`** is manipulated (ie, a **`TextView's`** text) in **`OnCreateView()`** (which is not on UI thread from my understanding), could it cause an exception in it (when this statement finally executes and trys to update the **`TextView`**, whenever that may be)?

For example, when the set text doesn't actually show up on the screen widget, could an exception have occurred that prevented it from showing that is eaten by the UI thread (or should the exception show up in the logger regardless)?

```
public class RecordView : Fragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, bundle); 

        ViewGroup thisView = (ViewGroup) inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Record, container, false);

        TextView tvData = thisView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv_data);

        tvData.Text = "can this cause exception in UI thread?";

        return thisView;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Yes, it can.  Especially when working with Fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnCreateView()` is always called on the Main Thread, so is every lifecycle method of fragments.
Actually, every method ever called from the entry point runs on the ui thread by default if not explicitly called from another thread.

No, if you try to change a view from another thread, an uncaught exception is thrown, crashing the app. There is no silent failing in this case.

also, you do not need to call super in `OnCreateView()`, the base method is empty.

I do not know how C# implements field access, is it mapped to a setter method automatically? if not, you HAVE TO use the setter method instead of accessing the field directly, because setText() does more than just changing a String field.

Comment: `public String Text { get; set; }` for Xamarin TextView.

Comment: If every fragment's lifecycle was called on the main thread, then I should be able to set the text of a TextView or SetItemChecked on a ListView in OnCreateView with no issue, however in some cases I must explicitly execute these such statements on the UI thread (and sometimes only if posted from OnResume()).

Comment: they are with no exception called from the main thread. use Looper.MyLooper().Thread == MainLooper.Thread in every lifecycle method to check.

Comment: from official xamarin-docs: As a developer, you can handle state changes by overriding these methods within an activity. It’s important to note, however, that all lifecycle methods are called on the UI thread and will block the OS from performing the next piece of UI work, such as hiding the current activity, displaying a new activity, etc. As such, code in these methods should be as brief as possible to make an application feel well performing. Any long-running tasks should be executed on a background thread.

Comment: I then wonder if my view update issues/anomalies from OnCreate are related these views not having their measurement info available their either (the rendering process is non-deterministic or something)?

Comment: I read that this morning. I brushed up against that when writing custom views that needed specific onMeasure and onLayout calculations. Back when I started, a GridView (which Calendar widget is) couldn't be nested in a ScrollView, so I had to build my own (needed to hide weekends so each weekday box was big enough to read, but needed weekends available just in case). I have an "input-field" abstraction (label+input+dropdown) that also implements onMeasure and onLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I can't address the specifics of your code but when trying to update a TextView (or EditView) from off the UI thread it will crash but it should show up in the logcat.

Here's an example of updating a TextView from a different thread.

```
public void addLine(String line){          //line is the text being passed in

    final String msg = line;               //this is critical!
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            rcvd.append("\n" + msg);      //rcvd is a TextView and we're just 
        }                                 //adding a line of text
    });
}
```

As for exceptions occurring but not showing up, I can't say with certainty but it is possible for the debugger to detach and it looks like your app just crashed. I went through this recently while stepping through, and at a certain point everything just died. In my case it was while stepping out of a BroadcastReceiver's onReceive method. Eventually I figured out that it only happened while stepping through, not when left to run.

Hopefully someone a lot smarter than me will weigh in but in the mean time, good luck!